# nodejs working fine on 8000 but not on 3000

Tags: node.js, server, port

I have a nodejs server code, as below. I am trying to run it on two separate instances of EC2 and funnily enough:

**Server 1**: Works perfectly fine.

**Server 2**: The nodejs server doesn't start listening. I type the command "nodejs myfile.js" or "node myfile.js" and hit return key, nothing happens and I get the command prompt back.

I am perplexed. Code as follows, main file:

```
var express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    oauthserver = require('oauth2-server');
var controllernew = require('./controllers/controllernew');


var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));

app.get('/index.html', controllernew.index);

app.oauth = oauthserver({
    model: require('./models/modeloauth'),
    grants: ['password'],
    debug: true,
    accessTokenLifetime: 31536000
});

app.get('/userOTP/:userid/username/:username', controllernew.getUserOTP);

app.all('/oauth/token', app.oauth.grant());
app.all('*', app.oauth.authorise());

app.use(app.oauth.errorHandler());

routes = require("./routes/items")();
app.use(routes);
var server = app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('server started at ' + server.address().port);
});
```

Small function for index function in controller for index.html request:

```
index: function(req, res, next){
    console.log("health check");
    res.write("All ok");
    res.end();
}
```

What am I missing on the second server, why isn't the code running. Is there a way to check if node has been installed properly?

Comment: is the port being used by some other process? Since you are running it in EC2, have you unblocked the firewall for the port 3000?

Comment: `lsof -iTCP:3000 -sTCP:LISTEN` - execute in terminal to check if port in use

Comment: it looks like that port is already used.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is solved and a pretty stupid oversight from my end was causing this. Posting the solution still, in case this helps anyone else.

My EC2 instance of the server was accepting inbound communication only on port 8080. I opened the port 3000 and port 80 and solved my problem.

The issue on the second instance of my server, however, is still open.